# Lindblad equation time ordered unitary

Tags: mathematics, density-operator

Edit: The question turned out to be quite obvious and in some sense even misleading, so I decided to delete it.

Comment: @jacob1729 Thank you Jacob for your comment. I now believe that the answer is yes and updated the question based on my guess, but I'm not certain if that's correct.

Comment: Right I see my error now, I got confused by the notation, I'll delete my original comment. I agree that I would expect the answer to be 'yes' and the accepted answer backs that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You note that the solution is "$\rho(t) = e^{L_DT} \mathcal{T}\exp(\int_0^T dt (-i\text{ad}_{H(t)}))\rho = e^{L_DT} (U\rho U^\dagger)$ for some unitary $U$ that describes the time-dependent Hamiltonian part." To show that $\rho (t) = U e^{L_DT} \rho U^\dagger$ as well, it's enough to show that the two superoperators $A \equiv e^{L_DT}$ and $B \equiv \mathcal{T}\exp(\int_0^T dt (-i\text{ad}_{H(t)})) = U \cdot U^\dagger$ commute, since then:

$$\rho (t) = A B \rho = B A \rho  =  U e^{L_DT} \rho U^\dagger$$

To show this, we just have to remember the physical meaning of the time-ordered exponential $B \equiv \mathcal{T}\exp(\int_0^T dt (-i\text{ad}_{H(t)}))$. This exponential generates the time evolution of $\rho$ under the Hamiltonian $H(t)$ over the interval $t=0$ to $t=T$. We can think of this time evolution as split into $N$ small (infinitesimal in the limit $N \to \infty$) timesteps of duration $\Delta t = T/N$. If we take $\Delta t$ small enough so that $H(t)$ is essentially constant over each timestep, then the evolution under $H(t)$ over each infinitesimal timestep will be generated by the superoperators $\exp( \Delta t (-i\text{ad}_{H(t_1)}))$, $\exp( \Delta t (-i\text{ad}_{H(t_2)}))$, $\exp( \Delta t (-i\text{ad}_{H(t_3)}))$... $\exp( \Delta t (-i\text{ad}_{H(t_N)}))$ , where $t_1 = 0$, $t_2 = \Delta t$, $t_3 = 2 \Delta t$... $t_N = (N-1) \Delta t$ are the beginnings of each time interval. Therefore, the total time evolution superoperator $B$ can be reexpressed as (in the limit $N \to \infty$):

$$B = \lim_{N \to \infty} \left[ \exp( \Delta t (-i\text{ad}_{H(t_N)}))... \exp( \Delta t (-i\text{ad}_{H(t_2)}))\exp( \Delta t (-i\text{ad}_{H(t_1)}))  \right]$$

But since $A$ commutes with each factor in this product of exponentials, it commutes with $B$ itself. This is what we needed to show.

Comment: Since $\mathcal{T}\exp\Big(\int_0^T dt (L_D  -i\text{ad}_{H(t)})\Big) = \mathcal{T}\exp\Big(\int_0^T dt (-i\text{ad}_{H(t)} + L_D)\Big)$, can we just argue $e^{L_DT} \mathcal{T}\exp(\int_0^T dt (-i\text{ad}_{H(t)})) = \mathcal{T}\exp(\int_0^T dt (-i\text{ad}_{H(t)}))e^{L_DT}$ so that the problem is immediately solved?

Comment: yes i think that's right. my answer is just a way of proving that you can pull $e^{L_D T}$ out of the time-ordered exponential in the way that you have.